# keyset and key different data type

Tags: java, arrays, collections, java-8, linkedhashmap

I am seeing a unique situation where my `keyset` and `key` of a `LinkedHashSet` are containing different data types as shown below

[image]

As you can see that the `key` is a `String` and the `keyset` is a `long`.

Following code is failing because of that:

```
modifiedRowKeys.toArray(new Long[modifiedRowKeys.size()]);
```

I get `ArrayStoreException` for `String` values.

I was able to replicate this from Angular application where i am sending a `Map<Long, Map<String,Object>>` to my Spring server which contains the data as shared in the pic.

[image]

**Edit 1**:

Please see following strange behavior in eclipse:

[image]

Could it be an issue with Jackson Mapper which we are using for conversion of objects ?

**Edit 2**:

The following code fails with `ClassCastException` saying

> String cannot be cast to Long

```
Set<Long> modifiedRowKeys = modifiedRowMap.keySet();
Long[] periodDateArray = new Long[modifiedRowKeys.size()];

int count = 0;
Iterator<Long> keyIterator = modifiedRowKeys.iterator();
while(keyIterator.hasNext()){
    Long key = keyIterator.next();
    System.out.println("key instanceof Long : " + (key instanceof Long));
    periodDateArray[count++] = Long.valueOf(key);
}
```

This seems pretty straight forward logic !

**Edit 3:**

I have recreated the problem as follows:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        CollectionsToArray collectionsToArray = new CollectionsToArray();

        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> mapOfNumbers = collectionsToArray.prepareStrangeNumbersSetFromMapOfMap();

        Object obj = mapOfNumbers;
        collectionsToArray.convertMapToKeySetToArray(obj);

    }

    private Map<String, Map<String, Object>> prepareStrangeNumbersSetFromMapOfMap() {
        Map<String, Map<String, Object>> longNumberMap = new LinkedHashMap<>();

        Map<String, Object> stringValueMap = new HashMap<>();
        stringValueMap.put("Adams", "Adithya");
        stringValueMap.put("Edge", 80);

        longNumberMap.put("1488376800000", stringValueMap);

        return longNumberMap;
    }

    private void convertMapToKeySetToArray(Object obj) {
        Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> mapOfNumbers = (Map<Long, Map<String, Object>>) obj;
        Set<Long> stringNumbers = mapOfNumbers.keySet();

        convertLongKeySetToArray(stringNumbers);
    }

    private void convertLongKeySetToArray(Set<Long> stringNumbers) {
        Long[] stringNumbersArray = stringNumbers.toArray(new Long[0]);
        Arrays.sort(stringNumbersArray);

        System.out.println(stringNumbersArray);
    }
```

Comment: Just to understand, you send an key,value list to a web page using long as key and then the page returns you back a list using a string as key?

Comment: Can you provide a [mcve]? Your explanation is unclear and you have not shown all your code... And please paste the code as text, not as an image.

Comment: And you need to put brakcets around `(key instanceof Long)` otherwise it won't compile.

Comment: I can tell about the "strange behavior" , use instead that line this: System.out.println("key instanceof Long:" + (key instanceof Long)); As you can see, the string was concatenated first with the value from key and then instanceof is not working between string and Long

Comment: my bad for not using the brakcets ! Thanks

Comment: @assylias : Noted.

Comment: You haven’t shown the declaration of `modifiedRowKeys`. Apparently, you are using a raw type somewhere and then insisting of using `Long`  after the unchecked operation, despite everything tells you that the keys are `String`s. In the debugger screenshot, no `Long` is visible…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I run the code in your "Edit 2" with a `Map<Long, String>` it compiles and runs fine. So the problem is not in what you've shown so far. As said above, try to create a [mcve] that does reproduce the problem.

My best guess is that you have something like this:

```
Map m = new HashMap (); //raw map received from jackson
m.put("abc", "def"); //it's in fact a Map<String, String>
Map<Long, String> modifiedRowMap = m; //but you cast it to something else
```

The rest of the code will compile but you will get an exception at runtime.

Comment: Please refer Edit 3.

Comment: @Adithya Well yes, you have a `Map<String, ...>` that you pass to a method as an `Object` and then you cast it to a `Map<Long, ...>`. Note that the compiler gives you a warning about an unchecked cast. Why would you expect your code to work?

Comment: actually, i captured the javascript object into Map<Long, Map<String, Object>> in Spring server using jackson mapper. I didn't intend to do that :). To recreate i have added the Edit 3.

Comment: I'm just saying that when you go from generics to raw type (Object in your case) to generic again, the compiler will emit a warning, assuming you know what you are doing. If the types don't match you get an exception and it's normal. Maybe the problem is where you parse the json input into an object with Jackson, but you haven't shown that code. You could try to create a small program where you have a hardcoded json input, map it with Jackson and reproduce the exception.

Comment: you are right about the warning and that warning should cause the following line to fail at runtime i believe 

Set<Long> stringNumbers = mapOfNumbers.keySet(); which doesn't. I will work on the sample program.

Comment: @Adithya No it will work fine - it's only when you retrieve an element from the set and allocate it to a Long that you will get an exception. For example :`Long n = stringNumbers.iterator().next();`

Comment: Why will i get the exception when i retrieve an element from the set ? Why not when i create the Set ? Isn't it wrong that the set which is showing that it is storing long values isn't actually having long values ?

Comment: @Adithya I don't know if it's right or wrong, but it's how the Java language specification have been written. Raw types are only there for backward compatibility and shouldn't be used lightly. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2770692/829571.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. Appreciate your help !

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing something, that `key` is a String, but `keySet` is actually a `Set` that uses `toString` to show the output with `[]`.

```
 Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
 set.add("1");
 set.add("2");
 System.out.println(set); // [1, 2]
```

So you have a `String` and a `Set` (not a long).

And this fails because `String` is known to *not* be a `Long` at compile-time, no runtime check is needed (also add the missing parentheses):

```
System.out.println("key instanceof Long" + (s instanceof Long));
```

Comment: If it was Set<String> i would understand; question is why is it a Set<Long> ?
Why does the code Set<Long> keys = modifiedRowMap.keySet(); compile ? It should compile for Set<String> right ?